# Unowned variables and async functions

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class that has an unowned variable. Like this:

```
class Student {
  unowned var school: School

  init(_ school: School) {
    self.school = school
  }
}
```

Now imagine I have an escaping async function in the class:

```
class Student {
  unowned var school: School

  init(_ school: School) {
    self.school = school
  }

  // When this function is first called
  // I can guarantee school has not been de-initialized
  func reportAttendance(completionHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    database.studentDidReportAttendance(student: self) {
      // I cannot guarantee school has not been deinitialized 
      // when this callback function returns!
      school.updateAttendance() 
      completionHandler()
    }
  }
}
```

My problem here is I can guarantee that when `reportAttendance()` it is called, that school has not been de-initalialized, but in the time it takes for the database to respond, I cannot guarantee that school won't be de-initialized. So if it is, then when the async block returns and tries to access school I get a run time error.

My question is how I can create a temporary strong reference to school when the function is first called, and then release it after I am able to safely run `updateAttendance` on school?

Thank you

Comment: Capture `self.school` in a local variable in your closure.  Alternatively, since presumably the intention is it isn't possible for a student to not have a school, you could use `weak self` in your closure

Comment: @Paulw11 Then what will release it just in case the closure is never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an x-y problem. If a Student's `school` can go out of existence while this Student still exists, that is an incorrect use of `unowned`. The precondition for saying `unowned` is that that must be absolutely impossible.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your answer. How do you suggest I create the relationship w/o making a strong reference cycle? I want my student to be required to have a school object, and school to have a strong list of students.

Comment: Then what is wrong with `weak` as suggested in the other answer?

Comment: If I understand correctly, student should have a weak reference to school or school should have a weak list of students? If student has a weak reference to school, then student could not call school.updateAttendance() if school was deinitialized. Is there anyway to capture school until after the async block completes?

Comment: Well, if you have a weak reference, you always do the weak-strong dance. That way, if the weak reference does still exist in the completion handler, your reference to it is strong during the completion handler. But deliberately retaining the reference beforehand is dangerous and goes against the whole spirit of memory management; a url session or an animation does retain its delegate, but in general you should not do that. After all, what if we _never_ complete? Or what harm is there to completing and discovering the target is gone? You just do nothing in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a local variable inside your function to keep a strong reference; see this test:

```
class School {
    deinit {
        print ("School.deinit")
    }
}

class Student {
    unowned var school:School
    
    init(_ school: School) {
      self.school = school
    }
    
    func printSchool() -> (() -> Void) {
        let strongSchool = self.school
        return { print ("I'm going to \(strongSchool)") }
    }
}


if (1==1) {
    var s:School? = School()
    let student = Student(s!)
    let p = student.printSchool()
    s = nil
    p() // Won't crash
}
```

Without `strongSchool`, the snippet crashes.

The thing is that we create a strong reference outside the closure - at this point in time you guarantee that it still exists - and then refer to this inside the closure. In this way, we

- do not capture the `student`/`self`, but only the `school`
- avoid a circular reference in case `database` is strongly reachable by the student and keeps itself the closure as a property (because `self` -> `database` -> `closure` -> `self`) and as long as `school` does not also reference database (well, it's more complicate to write than to think of)

But as @matt says, `unowned` is very dangerous and `weak` should be preferred, except for some uncommon cases where you have zillions of unowned objects which then would result in a large housekeeping overhead.